# GetContacts only returns 1 ContactPoint2D when 2 Objects are overlapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make 2 gameObjects moving towards each other. The objects have rigidbodies2D and colliders2D. When colliding, I want to get the contact points at the outside of the colliders. These can be up to 8 points. Now My objects are colliding but I only receive one Contact Point, which seems to be an Average of the Contact Points or the overlapping area. 
How Do I get every single point?

```
private ContactPoint2D[] contacts = new ContactPoint2D[10];

void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    collision.collider.GetContacts(contacts);


    foreach (ContactPoint2D contact in contacts)
    {
        Vector2 hitPoint = contact.point;

        if (hitPoint != testVector)
        {
            TestMarker.transform.position = new Vector3(hitPoint.x, hitPoint.y, -5.0f);
        }

        Debug.Log(hitPoint.ToString());
    };
}
```

So like in the following image visible I would like to track the contact points of the two objects. The green square starts at the point where the two objects hit each other the first time and then moves to the center as like an average value or sth.
Is this a normal behaviour?

[image: The two Objects]

How can I get all the contact points instead?

Comment: could you please add the code for `contacts` to your question? like anything initializing or altering it

Answer (score -1):

From the document:

> You should pass an array that is large enough to contain all the contacts you want returned

So you need to check whether the array size is suitable.

```
int count = collision.collider.GetContacts(contacts);
if(count > contacts.Length)
{
    Array.Resize(ref contacts, count);
    collision.collider.GetContacts(contacts);
}
```

Comment: I initialized my array with 10 spots, the Amount of Contacts I receive is 1 (in your example: count = 1).
So I assume the Array is large enough